# Add css file to resources but can not read it in Spring MVC 3.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I download source code from this link

https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/spring/spring-mvc-login-form-example.html

https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/wp-content/plugins/download-attachments/includes/download.php?id=206

I can run it well and I want to include bootstrap css to project.
In this project they setup config:

`<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />`

I tried to add bootstrap.css to resources folder and include it in head tag of jsp file.
But it can not read css file.

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

[image]

I added css to /webapp/resources folder.

Here are my project file structure.

[image]

What is problem in my source code?

Comment: Can you share file structure? I guess the file is in the wrong place. If it is a maven project, it should be `src/main/webapp/resources`

Comment: @grekier I added file structure to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I changed spring mvc from 3.x to version 4, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

this resources folder is placed under the main (main/resources) folder by default. hence, please move bootstrap.min.css file into main/resources.

[image]

Comment: I tried but it still not work.